# Sum of a row in a $n\times n$ matrix is one of its eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I wanted to show that it's not true but I cant find examples,
and I don't know how to prove that.
thanks
All the rows should have the same sum

Comment: For a matrix $A$ the condition "there exists a row such that the sum of its elements is an eigenvalue of $A$" is a polynomial condition on the entries of the matrix. Therefore, you should get a counterexample within the first three random matrices you can think of.

Comment: I can think of an eigenvector for this matrix.

Comment: How can I prove that ?@MarkBennet

Answer (score 2):

What about $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&2\\3&2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$?

- sum of the first row: $3$;
- sum of the second row: $5$;
- eigenvalues $-1$ and $4$.

---

If you assume also that *all* the rows have the same value $s$, then it is true. In that case, $(1,1,\ldots,1)$ is an eigenvector and its eigenvalue is $s$. Thats so because\begin{align}\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\ldots&a_{1n}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&\ldots&a_{2n}\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\ldots&a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}.\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{pmatrix}&=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}+a_{12}+\cdots+a_{1n}\\a_{21}+a_{22}+\cdots+a_{2n}\\\vdots\\a_{n1}+a_{n2}+\cdots+a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}\\&=\begin{pmatrix}s\\s\\\vdots\\s\end{pmatrix}\\&=s\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{pmatrix}.\end{align}

Comment: I wasn't clear. All the rows should have the same sum

Comment: @AvitalFunk I've edited my answer.

Comment: how can I prove that?

Comment: @AvitalFunk I've edited my answer again.